# Dell V725w Driver for Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, printer, ubuntu-13.04

I have a `Dell V725w` Printer and I wanted to print a document from my `Ubuntu 13.04` laptop. The driver for the printer is made for **Ubuntu 11.10**, but would it work with **Ubuntu 13.04**?

If not, is there some other way to allow me to print?

**EDIT:** 
When I downloaded a `Dell Printer` driver on **Ubuntu 12.04** it rendered the whole system useless (i.e. the OS crashed a lot and the driver was the reason).

Therefore, I would rather know whether the driver would work than trying it an messing up **Ubuntu**.

Comment: Why don't you try first, then ask? By this I mean it might work regardless of being from a former version. Has Dell released newer drivers?

Comment: That should work fine, little has changed since 11.10 that would affect that type of operation.  The majority of changes have been UI and kernel updates, none of which should affect driver use (at least that recent of a driver).

Comment: @DoktoroReichard see my edit to the question